# data augmentation error in fit generator function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-augmentation

I am trying to train a cnn model for face expression detection and to reduce the imbalance in the input classes, I use ImageDataGenerator from keras
to enlarge my dataset.

this is my code :

```
xs >> input 

ys >> output

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip =True, featurewise_center=True, featurewise_std_normalization=True)

data_gen.fit(xs)

history = self.model.fit_generator((data_gen.flow(xs,ys batch_size=self.batch_size)), steps_per_epoch=len(xs) / self.batch_size, epochs=epochs_num)
```

I generated a lot of images and fed it into the model to train it but it gives me this error :
could not broadcast input array from shape (28709,128) into shape (28709)

How can I identify the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

> It would be nice if you would share a running example of your code, so
>   that it is possible to reproduce the error.

My first guess is that some variable (probably your `batch_size`), that is 128, messes up the shape of your input.

Maybe this can be fixed with `reshape` of `numpy`.

Comment: i solve this error but i get another error in fit generator

history = self.model.fit_generator((data_gen.flow(ret,np.array(ys), batch_size=self.batch_size)),
  File "/home/wafaaismail/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image.py", line 916, in flow
    subset=subset)
  File "/home/wafaaismail/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image.py", line 1577, in __init__
    if type(x[1]) is not list:
IndexError: list index out of range